# How fit='smooth' is done in scatter3d?

Tags: r, scatter3d

http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/amazing-interactive-3d-scatter-plots-r-software-and-data-visualization

I see fit='smooth' is mentioned above. But it is not clear what is the underlying code to compute the smooth result. Could anybody show me the code to compute the smooth surface?

Comment: [gam](https://github.com/cran/car/blob/master/R/scatter3d.R#L255:L256)

Comment: There are many parameters of gam. Could you please provide the equivalent code for the smoothing given x, y, z?